# Django custom boolean field representation on template

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to use extended custom field on django model to modify the value printed on template. Now appears True/False, and should be Si/No.
It will be possible overwriting some of these custom field methods ?

```
class CustomBooleanField(models.BooleanField):

  def from_db_value()
    ...

  def to_python()
    ...

  def value_to_string()
    ...

class Budget(models.Model):

  periodic = app_fields.CustomBooleanField(verbose_name="Recurrente", default=False)
```

Anybody could help me please ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: One issue with changing `to_python` to return those strings is that comparisons will be affected (the string `No` is "truthy" and the string `Si` is "truthy" but not `True`). How many places are you planning on displaying this data? You couls use the `yesno` tag? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#yesno

Comment: It will be shown on many places, on list view of differents models with a table, and some models could has various boolean fields.